# How do I stop showing the status of my random forest parallel computing in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, random-forest

How can I clean up the output by removing these updates, I receive this by using: **`n_jobs = -1`** :

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 6 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  38 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 188 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 438 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 788 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 1238 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 1788 tasks      | elapsed:    0.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 2000 out of 2000 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 6 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  38 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 188 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 438 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 788 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 1238 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 1788 tasks      | elapsed:    0.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 2000 out of 2000 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"**How** do I stop showing the status of my random forest parallel computing in Python?"*

a) Using a published API

b) Using an inner-trick

c) Using an outer-trick

---

### A ) The *(scikit-learn)* `RandomForrest()`-API :

The published API has an item **`verbose`** with a default value of zero :

```
RandomForestRegressor( n_estimators = 100, *, criterion = 'mse',
                       max_depth = None, min_samples_split = 2, min_samples_leaf = 1, min_weight_fraction_leaf = 0.0, max_features = 'auto', max_leaf_nodes = None, min_impurity_decrease = 0.0, min_impurity_split = None, bootstrap = True, oob_score = False,
                       n_jobs = None, random_state = None,
                       verbose = 0, warm_start = False, ccp_alpha = 0.0, max_samples = None
                       )
```

Setting `verbose` anywhere higher increases the amount of output. Yet the snippet from the *RandomForest*-[source-code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L796) shows that scikit-learn actually passes this value to yet another constructor, the **`joblib.Parallel()delayed()`**, where more details get explained.

For which **`joblib`** explains :

> <sub>**`verbose`**: int, optional
>
>   
>
>       **The verbosity level**: if non zero, progress messages are printed. Above 50, the output is sent to `stdout`. The frequency of the messages increases with the verbosity level. If it more than 10, all iterations are reported.</sub>

This shows, that going anywhere above zero increases the Level-of-Detail reported plus creates a chance for us, if going, a bit counterintuitively, above 50... ( right, by hi-jacking the `stdout`... as shown in B) and C) below ).

---

### B ) The `stdout` inner-trick :

Given the `verbose = 51` or more was used, we may start ride a Dragon :

```
import sys
...
#--------------------------------------------------------------# MASK-stdout
anOldFileDESCRIPTOR = sys.stdout                               # .SAVE
pass;                 sys.stdout = open( 'aLogFILE.txt', 'w' ) # .SET
#--------------------------------------------------------------#############
# call RandomForestRegressor( ..., verbose = 51, ... )-method
...
#--------------------------------------------------------------#############
pass;                 sys.stdout.close()                       # .CLOSE
pass;                 sys.stdout = anOldFileDESCRIPTOR         # .RESTORE
#--------------------------------------------------------------# ORIG-stdout
```

This inner-trick masquerade shall steal all unwanted `stdout`-directed output and store it collected into the designated file.

---

### C ) The `stdout` outer-trick :

If not happy for having to revise the code-base as per B), one may go brute, using :

```
$ python MyRandomForestCODE.py > aLogFILE.txt
```

and the whole `stdout`-stream gets redirected straight from the shell/cmd-level.